# Do I have to repeat the noun here?

Tags: grammar, repetition

“Sociology, at least the type that follows the scientific method, is very reliable”.

Or:

“Sociology, at least the type of sociology that follows the scientific method, is very reliable”.

Is it correct either way, or do I have to repeat “sociology” as in the second example?

I’m primarily interested in formal written proper English.

Thank you!

Comment: The first is fine. It's obvious what "type" refers to.

Comment: Linguistically it sounds ok, but technically it gives the impression that there are 2 kinds of sociology, which might not sound good academically. Is there really two kinds of sociology? One which follows the scientific method, and the other which does not.

Comment: I studied sociology in the 1970s (briefly!) and I can tell you there are _at least_ two types! By one measure, two: qualitative sociology and quantitative sociology, and by another, three: positivist sociology, interpretive sociology, and critical sociology. Within these three types, four paradigms have come to dominate sociological thinking: structural functionalism, critical sociology, feminism, and symbolic interactionism.

Comment: I think there's an element of "sneering, looking down on" sociology that *doesn't* follow the scientific method. As recognised by @yunus, the phrasing as presented very strongly implies that such (obviously substandard) sociology ***does in fact exist*** - and is sufficiently common to be referenced as if it was a "recognised type". The same point can made without such an obvious "snide sideswipe" by simply rephrasing to *Sociology, **when it** follows the scientific method, is very reliable.* If you want to write formal text, keep personal opinions and value judgements to a minimum.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not at all, it’s precisely a piece against pseudoscience in sociology!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Both approaches are correct

The first is more economical with words and therefore preferable, but the second is not wrong.